# Calling REST Service from C#: Error 500

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest

I am trying to access a REST web service but get an error HTTP 500. There must be something I am not doing correct but couldn't find out. It is a publicly available service, otherwise I would have gotten a 403 error.

Here is my code:
(url is a string containing the web service URL, param is a string containing the parameters.)

```
        string url = @"http://crimemapping.edmontonpolice.ca/DataProvider.asmx/getOccurrenceInfo";
        string param = "{\"method\":\"send\",\"params\":[\"neighbourhoodID\":\"2\",\"crimeTypes\":\"Assault\",\"strStartDate\":\"2011,12,02\",\"strEndDate\":\"2012,03,01\"]}";
        // Reassigning param to increase readability.
        param = @"{""method"":""send"",""params"":[""neighbourhoodID"":""2"",""crimeTypes"":""Assault;Sexual Assaults;Break and Enter;Theft From Vehicle;Homicide;Theft Of Vehicle;Robbery;Theft Over $5000"",""strStartDate"":""2012,02,01"",""strEndDate"":""2012,03,01""]}";

        string response;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST"; //REST based-services using Post method
        request.ContentType = "application/json"; //tells request the content typs is JSON
        request.ContentLength = param.Length;

        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        requestWriter.Write(param);
        requestWriter.Close();

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
```

Comment: would need to see the value of the url variable as well as the param variable.  500 is an internal server error - means that either the service is wonky, or you passed in data that it doesnt know how to handle.

Comment: Are you sure the web service accepts json? Not all do.

Comment: Yes John, this one does accept JSON. I know that from Fiddler's trace.

Comment: @boo, I've put the values in the code above. Please take a look.

Comment: Your param would be a lot more readable were it in @"..." format instead of "..."

Comment: @boo, did what you suggested. Please let me know if the increased readability can help you identify the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I couldn't figure out in the beginning was that the JSON request cannot be made by any IP. It checks the IP before proceeding. The error I was getting was way off, so didn't help much.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

what's the type of

```
param
```

are you sure that this is json?

If you can see the request in fiddler just send the string from fiddler to verify that your .net infrastructure code is working.

But best thing to do is to grab the information from server, as it's been mentioned that 500 is internal server error. Error description will point out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks b0rg. Variable param is string.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what do you mean by "just send the string from fiddler". Should I try to send a similar request from fiddler to see what response I will get in there?

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi Fiddler can capture traffic, so you could simply turn Fiddler on and then try accessing the web service the same way you have been trying. See what Fiddler records.

Comment: John, it is a REST web service, so it does not have WSDL. Therefore it does not show anything meaningful if accessed directly from a browser, instead shows a generic .NET error page.

Comment: yes, this is why in fiddler you gonna grab the actual json string being sent to the service, and stick it into your code :)

Comment: Do you have working example for that particular service? Can you contact the authors for that?

Comment: Yes, I can see the log in fiddler when I go to http://crimemapping.edmontonpolice.ca/. In fiddler, I can see the exact call and the detailed response. The URL referenced is in the code sample above.